# Flink Slots/Parallelism vs Max CPU capabilities

Tags: python, parallel-processing, apache-flink

I'm trying to understand the logic behind flink's slots and parallelism configurations in .yaml document.

Official Flink Documentation states that for each core in your cpu, you have to allocate 1 slot and increase parallelism level by one simultaneously.

But i suppose that this is just a recommendation. If for a example i have a powerful core(e.g. the newest i7 with max GHz), it's different from having an old cpu with limited GHz. So running much more slots and parallelism than my system's cpu maxcores isn't irrational.

But is there any other way than just testing different configurations, to check my system's max capabilities with flink?

Just for the record, im using Flink's Batch Python API.

Answer (score 5):

It is recommended to assign each slot at least one CPU core because each operator is executed by at least 1 thread. Given that you don't execute blocking calls in your operator and the bandwidth is high enough to feed the operators constantly with new data, 1 slot per CPU core should keep your CPU busy.

If on the other hand, your operators issue blocking calls (e.g. communicating with an external DB), it sometimes might make sense to configure more slots than you have cores.

Answer (score 4):

There are several interesting points in your question.

- First, the slots in Flink are the processing capabilities that each taskmanager brings to the cluster, and they limit, first, the number of applications that can be executed on it, as well as the number of executable operators at the same time. Tentatively, a computer should not provide more processing power than CPU units present in it. Of course, this is true if all the tasks that run on it are computation intensive in CPU and low IO operations. If you have operators in your application highly blocking by IO operations there will be no problem in configuring more slots than CPU cores available in your taskmanager as @Till_Rohrmann said.
- On the other hand, the default parallelism is the number of CPU cores available to your application in the Flink cluster, although it is something you can specify as a parameter manually when you run your application or specify it in your code. Note that a Flink cluster can run multiple applications simultaneously and it is not convenient that only one block entire cluster, unless it is the target, so, the default parallelism is usually less than the number of slots available in your Cluster (the sum of all slots contributed by your taskmanagers).
- However, an application with parallelism 4 means, tentatively, that if it contains an stream: input().Map().Reduce().Sink() there should be 4 instances of each operator, so, the sum of cores used by the application Is greater than 4. But, this is something that the developers of Flink should explain ;)